# How could I add a image to my LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I want to be able to include two images to the bottom of my LWC, with a short description.

I want to be able to include these two images of my different map markers, and give a brief description of there differences via the bottom of my LWC.

[image]

[image]

**Conclusion:**

What is the best way to go about this?

Would I be able to save the two images to my LWC folder then import it to my LWC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SVGs directly in a template. Thus, you'd have something like:

```
<template>
<svg width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
 ...
</svg>
</template>
```

You can use CSS to position them as you'd like, even dynamically by JavaScript.  You could also use static resources, though that's more complicated than it really needs to be.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using static resources, because I wanted to use my PNG images since converting to a SVG file messed up my two images.